# macOS Catalina + Xcode 11 Error on reading file from project

Tags: directory, project, exc-bad-access, xcode11, macos-catalina

After upgrading to macOS Catalina with latest Xcode 11, I am not able to read files directly from user path when doing unit testing, example: 
`PROJECT_DIR + "/FolderX/myFile.json"`,
I keep getting error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)`

This is also happened when I am trying to open a couchbase lite database with custom path.
Error:
`error opening!: 14`
`Cannot open database, Error : Error Domain=SQLite Code=14 "unable to open database file" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unable to open database file}`

I believe this is an issue due to the read write access between my simulator and the latest Catalina.

My current **workaround** is to **add my files and database to target membership and read the files directly from `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]].bundlePath`**.
Is there any better fix to this? Like tweaking any setting to allow it to read files from custom path like in older versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if anyone is still struggling with this, I've moved all my projects outside of `~/Documents/`

it is strange that projects under `~/Documents/` doesnt get asked for read permission, other paths do!
I end up putting all my projects under `~/workspace/`

** for those who doesnt know, `~/` means `/Users/{your username}/`

Answer (score 7):

You might try looking in SystemPreferences > Security&Privacy > Privacy tab. From there, scroll down to "Files and Folders" <-- There's where you can see programs and the folders they have been granted access to in Catalina.

Personally, I didn't have time to waste figuring out how the new file permissions are supposed to work, so I let Xcode have full disk permission. (Right above the "files and folders" is "Full Disk Access".

Of course, that solved all my issues... after I get a chance to play with the new file permissions, I may revoke that access and give it explicit folder access.

Comment: I have added everything, the Xcode, simulator, build server into the Full Disk Access settings.
I am still getting read permission error.

I am trying to read file outside of my simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Check your File Access settings in the App Sandbox in your project's settings, under Signing and Capabilities. For example, I couldn't access files in `/Users/Bert/Downloads`, even after turning on Full Disk Access in Security and Privacy in System Preferences. I had to grant read access to the Downloads Folder in App Sandbox settings.

[image: Screenshot of Project Settings]